# How to publish a library of Vue.js components?

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, ecmascript-6, vue.js

I am working on a project containing a Vuex module and an abstract components that users can extend from.

I would love to publish this on NPM to clean up my codebase and pull this away from my project as a solid well tested module. I have specified the main file in `package.json` to load an index which imports everything I want to expose:

https://github.com/stephan-v/vue-search-filters/

The index contains this at the moment:

```
import AbstractFilter from './src/components/filters/abstract/AbstractFilter.vue';
import Search from './src/store/modules/search';

module.exports = {
    AbstractFilter,
    Search
};
```

For this to work I need to transpile this since a babel compiler normally won't transpile files imported from node_modules(Correct me if I am wrong here). Besides that I would probably be a good idea to do this so it can be used by different systems.

How do I transpile only the files that I need though with Webpack? Do I have to create a separate config for this?

What does a config like that look like? I know the vue-cli has a `build` command for one single file component but this is a bit different.

Any tips or suggestions on how to transpile something like this are welcome.

**Edit**

This seems like a good start as well:

https://github.com/Akryum/vue-share-components

The most import thing for Webpack users to notice is that you need to transpile your files in UMD which can be set by:

```
libraryTarget: 'umd'
```

This will make sure your are transpiling for `Universal Module Definition`, meaning your code will work in different environments like AMD,CommonJS, as a simple script tag, etc.

Besides that it is import to provide the externals property in webpack:

```
externals: {}
```

Here you can define which libraries your project users but should not be built into your `dist` file. For example you don't want the Vue library to be compiled / transpiled into the source of your NPM package.

I will research a bit more, so far the best options looks like to create a custom project myself If I want flexibility and unit testing.

**Webpack docs**

This is also a useful page which goes in depth about how to publish something with Webpack:

https://webpack.js.org/guides/author-libraries/#add-librarytarget

Comment: I am baffled at how much of a pain it is to simply create a vue components library that uses SCF files with Typescript blocks, and transpiles itself to esm modules. You'd think that nowadays, given the maturity of each tools, this would be a breeze, but no! Makes me want to scream...

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The best way probably will be to build the module and set `main` in your `package.json` to `my_dist/my_index.js`. Otherwise every project that will use your module will have to add it to `include` which is tedious.

You will also want your webpack build to follow UMD (Universal Module Definition). For that you must set `libraryTarget` to `umd`:

```
...
output: {
  filename: 'index.js',
  library:'my_lib_name',
  libraryTarget: 'umd'
},
...
```

Also a good thing will be to add `Vue` to `externals` so that you didn't pack extra 200kb of vue library.

```
externals: {
  vue: 'vue'
},
resolve: {
  alias: {
    'vue$': 'vue/dist/vue.esm.js'
  }
}
```

And add it to `peerDependencies` in `package.json`:

```
...
"peerDependencies": {
  "vue": "^2.0.0"
},
"devDependencies": {
  "vue": "^2.0.0"
}
...
```

If you need an existing example of how to pack a vue.js component, you can take a look in one of the modules I maintain:

https://github.com/euvl/vue-js-popover

Particularly `webpack.config.js` and `package.json` will be interesting for you.

Comment: Thanks this looks like a very good start and probably what I am looking for. I will check it out tonight and let you know if it answers my question.

Comment: Just curious, did you create the webpack config for this project yourself or did you took parts from another project that also builds for `umd`?

Comment: Also, how do you develop with this project? There is no watcher and no import of Vue.js. It looks like you can only develop by hooking this entire project up to a repo which actually imports Vue how do you deal with this? I would preferably have a completely independent project so I can run unit tests, e2e tests, etc. as well.

Comment: @Stephan-v at first I used vue cli webpack-simple config, because I could not understand a thing in webpack conf :D But with doing more projects & getting more experience with it - I've tweaked it to fit my needs.

Comment: @Stephan-v the setup I have found convenient for myself is: i build the library manually when i make changes using `npm run build` and i have `demo` folder where I run `npm run dev` once and test the changes using my regression tests (basically my demo use-cases).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150101/discussion-between-yev-and-stephan-v).

Answer (score 0):

I was searching for a similar solution and found rollup https://github.com/thgh/rollup-plugin-vue2 (but was not able to make it work) and this component https://github.com/leftstick/vue-expand-ball where all the component code gets compiled to one reusable js-file.
I know that's not a proper solution but maybe it's sufficient for your needs.

Comment: Rollup is just another bundling tool though, I would like to stay within the Webpack eco system since that is what I am already using. I know how to transpile files I just need a way to transpile each file separately into generic ES5 files suitable for all module systems. Thanks for your answer though.