# Publishing a Vuejs component as a package on npm

Tags: javascript, npm, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I created a vuejs2 project (using webpack) with 2 components, I want to publish this project on npm as a package so that I can use all the components inside this project with multiple projects (reusable components).

I published the project on npm `npm publish` and installed the package using npm install `my-components`, I found the project inside `node_modules` but it was with the whole source code, as if I copy/pasted the project there.

Also when I try to run `npm build dist` I am getting an error:

> npm ERR! Darwin 16.6.0
>
> npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "run" "dist"
>
> npm ERR! node v6.9.2
>
> npm ERR! npm v3.10.9
>
> npm ERR! missing script: dist
>
> npm ERR! npm ERR! If you need help, you
> may report this error at: npm ERR!
> https://github.com/npm/npm/issues
>
> npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
> npm ERR!
> /Users/myuser/Documents/Projects/my-components/npm-debug.log

Inside my project (https://github.com/Trelllis/my-components), there is a component called vue-version which I can't use and the project my-components isn't resolved.

How can I publish this project properly with all its components?

Thanks

Comment: Look at this similar Question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45298859/how-to-publish-a-library-of-vue-js-components/45299467#45299467 the vue-share template can solve your problem ,its  linked there.

Answer (score 0):

That's normal to have the full code if you included it the npm module. If you want a folder to be removed from npm, you can create a `.npmignore` at the root of your project, with the same syntax as `.gitignore` files. Find documentation for npmignore [here](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/developers#keeping-files-out-of-your-package).

For your second problem, you probably want to run `npm run build`, which execute [this file](https://github.com/Trelllis/my-components/blob/master/build/build.js). At least I see nothing that could lead in your project to a valid use of `npm build dist` (there is no dist folder). See [general documentation for npm scripts](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scripts), and documentation for [npm build](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/build).

Comment: I ran `npm build` then installed the package, but when importing it (`import Mycomponents from 'my-components'`), I am getting:
`Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'my-components' in '/Users/myuser/Documents/Projects/trellis-admin-ui/src/components'`

Comment: Why are you trying to run npm build?

Comment: forget about npm build, I am installing my application but the other project couldn't resolve the `vue-version` component

Comment: How are you trying to import it?

Comment: import vueVersion from 'vue-version'

Comment: If you want to import it this way, you need to name your package 'vue-version'. Then add the path of your vue version component to your `package.json`, into the field `main`. Can be for example `"main": "dist/vue-version.js"` (assuming you have a dist folder with your compiled component).

Comment: how can I compile each component as a separate file into the dist folder?